# "Assigning to teams" as a function

Tags: functions, notation, binomial-coefficients

Given sets $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and $B=\{r,g,b\}$, with $r$, $g$ and $b$ teams (red, green and blue) of sizes $2$, $3$ and $4$, respectively, can we use function notation to express the idea of assigning a given number of elements from $A$ to each team?

Comment: (I'm so sorry, site confusion - please disregard my previous comment.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber OK, no worries.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know here? Yes, you can explicitly define some function $f: A \to B$ that maps two elements to $r$, three to $g$, and the remaining four to $b$. In fact there are $1260$ unique ways of doing this, one of which is the following: $1 \to r, 2 \to r, 3 \to g, 4 \to g, 5 \to g, 6\to b, 7 \to b, 8 \to b, 9 \to b$

Comment: @WaveX The motivation is that I'm trying to understand the significance of 'distinctness' in combinations and permutations, and I thought function notation might help clarify the difference between assigning elements to distinct sets/teams vs indistinct sets/teams. When I tried to express it, I found myself trying to assign elements from a domain to elements inside sets in the codomain.

Comment: @mjc If you're interested in using functions to clarify distinctness/indistinctness, it'd be better to add that to your question - the question as written now is difficult to know how to answer, but adding that detail makes it fairly clear how to answer.

Comment: @MiloBrandt OK, thanks for the tip. I'll start a new question now I have a better idea what I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a variant  which might  fit the needs.

> Let  $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and $B=\{r,g,b\}$. We consider a function $f$ which fulfills
>   \begin{align*}
> &f:A\to  B\\
> &|f^{-1}(r)|=2, |f^{-1}(g)|=3, |f^{-1}(b)|=4\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}

- Since $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ it has domain $A$ and each of the nine elements of $A$ is mapped to $B$.
- The pre-images of $\{r,g,b\}$ have according to (1) a size of $2,3$ and $4$ giving a sum of $2+3+4=9$. Since each of the nine elements of $A$ has to be addressed, (1) implies we have a partitioning of $A$.

So we describe with $f$ one out of $\binom{9}{2}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{4}=1\,260$ functions from $A$ to $B$ which fulfill (1).

Comment: Thanks for this. As it happens, since posting the question I'd also come to the idea of defining $f$ using its preimages. This prompted me to wonder whether the domain of $f$ should be a subset of $P(A)$.

Comment: @mjc: You're welcome. As long as you don't need subsets of $A$ as objects by its own, there is no need to change anything.